# Display characters in grid but i have to save bit value in database

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using checkbox in windows form application for selecting status active/inactive, but in database i used bit datatype,it is saving the result as 1/0,but in gridview i have to display it as active or inactive, can any one please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your Active and Inactive value into bit value (1/0). May be it could give you a sample:

```
byte value = 0;

if(checkBox1.Checked) 
{
   value = 1;
}

//your code to save to database
```